# Don't allow to create a image file in external storage in react native app (android)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, file

I am making an application with react native and when I try to create a file in an external storage location I get an error. The error is "never_ask_again", the problem is that it never asks me if I give permissions to the application, it only works in READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE where it asks me and I give permission and in WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE I do not get the notification to give permission.

I already have the permissions in androidmanifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
```

I am also cheking the read and write permission using the following code:

```
PermissionsAndroid.check(
  PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
).then(granted => {
  if (!granted) {
    PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    ]).then(result => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you please try to reset the app by going into app settings and then clearing all the stuff? Might be that it asked you sometime earlier where you might be testing never ask again thing 

Comment: i deleted the cache and the app data, i even reinstalled it and it still doesn't work.